# Unknown error getting started with Prisma

Tags: prisma

I've got an odd error, I've been googling to no end and have been unable to figure this out.

I've got a prisma.schema looking like this;

```
// This is your Prisma schema file,
// learn more about it in the docs: https://pris.ly/d/prisma-schema

generator client {
  provider = "prisma-client-js"
}

datasource db {
  provider = "postgresql"
  url      = env("DATABASE_URL")
}

model Account {
  id                 String  @id @default(cuid())
  userId             String
  type               String
  provider           String
  providerAccountId  String
  refresh_token      String?  @db.Text
  access_token       String?  @db.Text
  expires_at         Int?
  token_type         String?
  scope              String?
  id_token           String?  @db.Text
  session_state      String?
  user User @relation(fields: [userId], references: [id], onDelete: Cascade)
  @@unique([provider, providerAccountId])
}

model Session {
  id           String   @id @default(cuid())
  sessionToken String   @unique
  userId       String
  expires      DateTime
  user         User     @relation(fields: [userId], references: [id], onDelete: Cascade)
}

model User {
  id            String    @id @default(cuid())
  name          String?
  email         String   @unique
  emailVerified DateTime?
  image         String?
  accounts      Account[]
  sessions      Session[]
}

model VerificationToken {
  identifier String
  token      String   @unique
  expires    DateTime
  @@unique([identifier, token])
}
```

and a addUser.ts file looking like this...

```
// Next.js API route support: https://nextjs.org/docs/api-routes/introduction
import { User, PrismaClient } from '@prisma/client';
import type { NextApiRequest, NextApiResponse } from 'next';

type Data = {
  name: string;
};

const prisma = new PrismaClient();

export default async(req: NextApiRequest, res: NextApiResponse) => {
  const createUser: User = await prisma.user.create({
    data:{
        name: `${Math.random() * 10000}`,
        email: `${Math.random() * 10000}@gmail.com`,
    }
  });
  res.json('user created succesfully');
}
```

Trouble is when I run the code I get this error....

```
Error: 
Invalid `prisma.user.create()` invocation:

{
  data: {
    name: '8096.003938770688',
    email: '8343.394432092025@gmail.com'
    ~~~~~
  }
}

Unknown arg `email` in data.email for type UserCreateInput. Did you mean `name`? Available args:
type UserCreateInput {
  name: String
}
```

But if I look at the UserCreateInput type (I haven't made any changes to this file, I've used `prisma generate` to match my schema when I've made changes to it) I can see this....

```
export type UserCreateInput = {
    id?: string
    name?: string | null
    email: string
    emailVerified?: Date | string | null
    image?: string | null
    accounts?: AccountCreateNestedManyWithoutUserInput
    sessions?: SessionCreateNestedManyWithoutUserInput
  }
```

If I comment out the line email: `${Math.random() * 10000}@gmail.com`, and set the schema to "email  String? @unique" it works fine and creates the entry into the DB as expected, so it seems to be something with my email field but I can't figure out what.

I have been following multiple guides but none of them seem to expect this issue or have any resolutions for it.

I should point out, I am fairly new to development, and I'm not a developer by trade, so this is more of a learning thing for me :)

Appreciate your time guys

Answer (score 0):

The `prisma.schema` file looks fine, did you push the changes after making changes to your schema file.
Every time you make the changes to your schema, you need to run the command `npx prisma generate` and also `npx prisma db push` to actually update the db.

You can always run `npx prisma studio` in a separate terminal which will give you a web interface to interact and check with the db.